# How to stop application on Wildfly 8.2.1 final server using Eclipse - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I'm writing unit tests for Java EE beans that run on Wildfly 8.2.1 final, I've been tasked to stop the application in code, after all the tests have been completed. Can someone direct me how to do that, I'm quite new to Java EE and web programming.

I've tried using this code:

```
String jbossBinDir = System.getProperty("jboss.server.base.dir").replace("standalone", "bin");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh " + jbossBinDir + "/jboss-cli.sh -c command=shutdown");
```

But all this seems to do is stop the entire Wildfly server.

Comment: What kind of build environment are you running in? Is it maven or some kind of custom eclipse plugin?

Comment: I think it is maven here is a screenshot of installed software https://s22.postimg.org/p6t5b2oc1/plugins.png

The idea is to stop the execution the application, and when full publish is called then the application should reset and work again, i still have no clue on how to do that, i tried throwing runtime exceptions but then when i call publish it doesn't restart

Comment: It's not very clear to me on what you're trying to do. I'm not sure what you mean by "stop the execution the application". Web applications generally require some kind of request. I *think* you want to undeploy the application, but I'm not certain that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Application should stop execution, which means endpoints should not be visible when i do that. I must not stop or crash Wildfly/Jboss server. I also must not use jboss-cli command calling in eclipse-IDE. I tried throwing runtime exepction but then i can't republish the server without restarting :(. Also where can i find the full list of commands of jboss-cli which i can ivoke after using jboss-cli --connect, like shutdown(restart=true)

Comment: It sounds like you want to undeploy the EAR. I'm not really following how eclipse is involved however. Or how you application is even deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [dzone article](https://dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java) gives you something about how to stop programmatically java application. I believe you are writing unit test then no need to implements long code. So here my tricky ways,

1. Throw Run times error in your test or
2. I think you write Java EE application. So make your login session invalidate
   or logout

Comment: I need to programmatically shutdown deployed EAR application after the tests are finished but without killing Wildfly server.